# CreatePipe / CreateProcess invalid Read handle

Tags: windows, delphi, winapi, pipe

I'm trying to use a pipe for process communication, but an attempt to read from the Read handle leads to an error.

First, here is some test code to see if the pipe works at all, but it doesn't:

```
procedure TestPipe;
const
  SecConst: TSecurityAttributes = (nLength: SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes); bInheritHandle: true);
var
  Security: TSecurityAttributes;
  PipeRead, PipeWrite: THandle;
  s: string;
begin
  Security:= SecConst;
  Win32Check(CreatePipe(PipeRead, PipeWrite, @Security, 0));
  Win32Check(SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, PipeWrite));
  Win32Check(SetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE, PipeRead));
  Writeln('555');
  Readln(s);  // <-- Hangs here!
  Assert(s = '555');
end;
```

Instead of reading the string I've written to the pipe, the program hangs.

Here is the actual code that I wanted to use with slight modifications:

```
procedure StartWorker;
const
  SecConst: TSecurityAttributes = (nLength: SizeOf(TSecurityAttributes); bInheritHandle: true);
var
  Security: TSecurityAttributes;
  PipeRead, PipeWrite: THandle;
  SI: TStartupInfo; PI: TProcessInformation;
  s: string;
begin
  Security:= SecConst;
  Win32Check(CreatePipe(PipeRead, PipeWrite, @Security, 0));
  Win32Check(SetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE, PipeWrite));

  FillChar(SI, SizeOf(SI), 0);
  FillChar(PI, SizeOf(PI), 0);
  SI.cb:= SizeOf(SI);
  SI.dwFlags:= STARTF_FORCEOFFFEEDBACK or STARTF_USESTDHANDLES;
  SI.hStdInput:= PipeRead;
  SI.hStdOutput:= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  SI.hStdError:= INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;
  s:= 'Worker.exe';
  UniqueString(s);
  Win32Check(CreateProcess(nil, PChar(s), nil, nil, false, 0, nil, nil, SI, PI));
  CloseHandle(PI.hThread);
  CloseHandle(PI.hProcess);
end;
```

In this case, the child process gets an invalid StdIn handle. The child process simply does an infinite 'Readln' loop (and is supposed to do something with the string it reads). First call to 'Readln' fails with 'I/O error 6' (The handle is invalid).

Comment: Your pipe handles are not set to be inheritable. In the `CreateProcess` call you didn't pass `true` for parameter `bInheritHandles`. I suggest to read up on how to redirect child processes from the many resources already available on the web.

Comment: Thank you! That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::pair<int, std::string> LaunchExeFileAndWaitFull(std::string exe, std::string arg, std::string workdir)
{
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES     sa;
    HANDLE                  hRead, hWrite;
    char                    buf[8000] = { 0 };
    STARTUPINFOA            si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION     pi;
    DWORD                   bytesRead;
    DWORD                   bytesWrite;
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    RtlSecureZeroMemory(&sa, sizeof(sa));
    int br = 0;
    DWORD exitcode = 0;
    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.lpSecurityDescriptor = NULL;
    sa.bInheritHandle = true;
    if (!CreatePipe(&hRead, &hWrite, &sa, 8000))
    {
        return std::make_pair(0, "启动进程失败");
    }


    si.cb = sizeof(si);




    si.hStdOutput = hWrite;
    si.hStdError = hWrite;
    si.hStdInput = hRead;
    si.dwFlags = STARTF_USESTDHANDLES | STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW;
    si.wShowWindow = SW_HIDE;


    std::string cmdline = exe;
    if (!arg.empty())
    {
        cmdline += +" " + arg;
    }
    LPSTR pcmdline = _strdup(cmdline.c_str());
    LPCSTR lpCurrentDirectory = nullptr;
    if (!workdir.empty())
    {
        lpCurrentDirectory = workdir.c_str();
    }
    // Start the child process. 
    if (CreateProcessA(NULL,   // No module name (use command line)
        pcmdline,  // Command line
        NULL,
        NULL,
        TRUE,
        NULL,
        NULL,
        lpCurrentDirectory,
        &si,
        &pi)
        )
    {       


        while (1)
        {


            PeekNamedPipe(hRead, buf, 8000, &bytesRead, &bytesWrite, NULL);
            if (bytesRead != 0)
            {
                if (!ReadFile(hRead, buf + br, 8000, &bytesRead, NULL))
                    break;
                br += bytesRead;
            }
            else
            {
                if (::WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, 1000) == WAIT_OBJECT_0) {


                    PeekNamedPipe(hRead, buf, 8000, &bytesRead, &bytesWrite, NULL);
                    if (bytesRead == 0)
                    {
                        break;
                    }


                }
            }
        }
        CloseHandle(hWrite);
        CloseHandle(hRead);
        ::GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &exitcode);
        wpa_printf(MSG_DEBUG, "Run Pid:=>%d,ret:=>%d,cmd:=>%s\r\n", pi.dwProcessId, exitcode, pcmdline);
        free(pcmdline);
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);


        std::string ret = "启动进程成功,返回值:" + std::to_string(exitcode) + ",命令行输出:";
        int retcode = 0;
        if (exitcode == 0)
        {
            retcode = 1;
        }
        ret.append(buf);
        return std::make_pair(retcode, ret);
    }
    else
    {
        exitcode = GetLastError();
        wpa_printf(MSG_DEBUG, "Run Pid :=> % d, ret :=> % d, cmd :=> % s\r\n", pi.dwProcessId, exitcode, pcmdline);
        free(pcmdline);
        std::string ret = "启动进程失败,错误码:" + std::to_string(exitcode);
        return std::make_pair(0, ret);
    }
    return std::make_pair(0, "启动进程失败");
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).